# Laravel Mailables pass several variables to __construct() and Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have a contact form like any other contact form (it has a field for a name, email, subject, and message). 
I created a FormController.php in which I validate my from and make use of Mail to send my form. 
I also generated a Mailable using `php artisan make:mail FormMail --markdown=emails.form.data`.

I hav the following problems:

1. I want to pass the email someone enters into the ->from() method, but I get an error that says `Undefined variable`. How can I pull that specific value so that when I receive an email it says it comes from the person who is trying to contact me? 
   So far, I've been getting the default email provided in Laravel (hello@example.com). I want the email to be the one a user enters. For instance emily@mail.com
   [image: screenshot]

   2. I cannot pass the subject into the ->subject() method. I get the same error as #1

Here is my FormController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Mail\FormMail;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class FormController extends Controller
{
    public function getContacto() {
        return view('pages.contacto');
    }

    public function postContacto(Request $request) {
        $email = 'random@email.com';
        $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|regex:/^[\pL\pM\p{Zs}.-]+$/u',
        'email1' => 'required|email',
        'email2' => 'required|email|same:email1',
        'subject' => 'required|max:70',
        'bodyMessage' => 'required|max:500'
        ];

        $this->validate($request, $rules);

        $name = $request->name;
        $email1 = $request->email1;
        $subject = $request->subject;
        $bodyMessage = $request->bodyMessage;

        Mail::to($email)->send(new FormMail($name, $email1, $subject, $bodyMessage));

        return view('pages.sent');
    }
}
```

Here is my mailable FormMail.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class FormMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $name;
    public $email1;
    public $subject;
    public $bodyMessage;

    /**
    * Create a new message instance.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function __construct($name, $email1, $subject, $bodyMessage)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->email1 = $email1;
        $this->subject = $subject;
        $this->bodyMessage = $bodyMessage;
    }

    /**
    * Build the message.
    *
    * @return $this
    */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->with([
        'name' => $this->name,
        'subject' => $this->subject,
        'bodyMessage' => $this->bodyMessage
        ])
        ->markdown('emails.form.data');


        /*DOES NOT WORK 
          return $this->from($email1)->subject($subject)->with([
                        'name' => $this->name,
                        'email1' => $this->email1])
                      ->markdown('emails.form.data');*/
    }
}
```

Any help and error you see in my code will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please add the code of your mail's view.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you're not passing the `from` and `subject` data correctly, the data is stored your class properties (you're using a local variable which is not defined).

You can pass the name in the 2nd argument in the `from` method, same goes with the `subject` method just pass the subject there. Also the you can pass in the `with` method the variables you want to use in your email template view. So your `FormMail.php` will become:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class FormMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $name;
    public $email1;
    public $subject;
    public $bodyMessage;

    /**
    * Create a new message instance.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function __construct($name, $email1, $subject, $bodyMessage)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->email1 = $email1;
        $this->subject = $subject;
        $this->bodyMessage = $bodyMessage;
    }

    /**
    * Build the message.
    *
    * @return $this
    */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from($this->email1, $this->name)->subject($this->subject)->with([
        'name' => $this->name,
        'subject' => $this->subject,
        'bodyMessage' => $this->bodyMessage
        ])
        ->markdown('emails.form.data');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please accept my answer as best answer if you find it helpful.